# Logarithmic singularity of complete elliptic functions of the first kinds.

Tags: reference-request

My professor, in class, talked about logarithmic singularity of complete elliptic functions of the first kinds:
$$ 
K(k) =\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}}
$$
I want to know a reference (online if possibile) about that subject. Can anyone tell me?
thank you very much

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442618/), might be helpful as it expresses $K'/K$ with the help of $\log k$.

Comment: Besides, $K(k)$ is a (complete) [elliptic *integral*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral), an [elliptic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_function) would be something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These might help.

http://www.mhtlab.uwaterloo.ca/courses/me755/web_chap3.pdf

http://web.mst.edu/~lmhall/SPFNS/sfch3.pdf

In addition you might find some useful information for reference in this book,

http://books.google.ca/books?id=MtU8uP7XMvoC&pg=PA587&dq=complete+elliptic+integral+of+the+first+kind+university&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ag2jUvGHJufgsATgwoHIDg&ved=0CDoQ6wEwAg#v=onepage&q=complete%20elliptic%20integral%20of%20the%20first%20kind%20university&f=false

Comment: The first two linked docs do not cover logarithmic singularities, and the third is blocked due to its viewing limit.