# Questions about reduction of elliptic integrals and general calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, elliptic-integrals

I am working on a numerical problem and trying to simplify elliptic integrals to reduce computational costs.
I found [a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2059819/reduction-of-elliptic-integrals-of-special-type?rq=1) that is similar to my case, but I don't understand part of it.
I'll take that part out and talk about it.
$$H_n(k)=\int_0^1 \frac{t^{2n}dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}\sqrt{1-kt^2}}$$
Introducing for simplicity function $\rho_k=\sqrt{1−kt^2}$,
$$H_n(k)=\int_0^1 \frac{t^{2n}}{\rho_1 \rho_k} dt=-\int_0^1 \frac{t^{2n}}{\rho_k}d\rho_1=\int_0^1 \rho_1d \frac{t^{2n}}{\rho_k}...$$
I don't understand the equation transformation for the third equal sign in the above equation.
I think there is a deformation of $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=-\int_0^1xdf(x)$, but I don't understand why it is valid.
I would appreciate it if you could tell me.

Comment: $\sqrt{1-t}\neq \rho_1$ so your simplification is not correct.

Comment: @Zima: That's a typo; it's supposed to be $\sqrt{1-t^2}$ (if you look at the linked question).

Comment: I think it might have been more appropriate to write a comment to that answer, requesting clarification. But anyway, it's just integration by parts.

Comment: I'm sorry.I didn't quite understand the usage and conventions.   
Use integration by parts.  
$\int_0^1 f(x)dx=-\int_0^1 xdf(x)+\int_0^1 d(xf(x))$  
So, do I just make sure that $0f(0)=1f(1)$ holds?

Answer (score 1):

$$H_n(k)=\int_0^1 \frac{t^{2n}}{\rho_1 \rho_k} dt=-\int_0^1 \frac{t^{\color{red}{2n-1}}}{\rho_k}d\rho_1=\int_0^1 \rho_1d \frac{\color{red}{t^{2n-1}}}{\rho_k}...$$
The first equality:
$$\dfrac {d \rho_1}{dt}=\dfrac {d \sqrt {1-t^2}}{dt}$$
$$\dfrac {d \rho_1}{dt}=-\dfrac t {\sqrt {1-t^2}}$$
$$\dfrac {d \rho_1}{dt}=-\dfrac t {\rho_1}$$
$$\implies {d \rho_1}=-\dfrac t {\rho_1}dt$$
The second equality is just an integration by part:
$$-\int_0^1 \frac{t^{\color{red}{2n-1}}}{\rho_k}d\rho_1=\Bigg| - \frac{t^{{2n-1}}}{\rho_k}\rho_1\Bigg|_0^1+\int_0^1 \rho_1 \left ( \frac{t^{{2n-1}}}{\rho_k}\right)'dt$$
$$-\int_0^1 \frac{t^{{2n-1}}}{\rho_k}d\rho_1=\int_0^1 \rho_1 d\left ( \frac{t^{{2n-1}}}{\rho_k}\right)$$