# What are the polynomials E1(1-m) and E2(1-m) in E(m) = E1(1-m)+ E2(1-m)Ln(1-m)

Tags: elliptic-integrals

The complete elliptic integrals K(m)  and E(m)  have very similar infinite series in powers of m,  but convergence relies on m being less than say 0.5.

For m near 1,  they are expanded in powers of 1-m instead as that  is now less than 0.5.

K(m)  = K1(1-m) -K2(1-m)Ln(1-m) 
where K1 and K2  are polynomials I located in Cody 1963,  "Chebyshev approximations....."
The series for E(m) also with the Ln term  (in my question) is mentioned in Cody but he doesn't disclose the polynomial coefficients. I have searched high and low for them and come up blank.
Can anybody help?
BTW  Wolfram doesn't give enough terms to be able to deduce the coefficient sequence.

Comment: The relation which I know of is described here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/442618/72031

Comment: Thank you for that reference. Can you define K'(k)  for me?  Abramovitz and Stegun use that notation for K(k')  where k'  is the complementary modulus root(1-k^2)

Comment: Yes the symbol $K'$ refers to $K(k') $ as in Abramovitz.